# Dlookup in Access and matrices

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do you find a matching value in access within a 15 x 15 matrix similar to B D A. 6.25. 5.23 C. 7. 9

In other words, how do I lookup the value CD in the matrix within access and then pass the value to another function?

Comment: Your question is very unclear - please edit your question and format your matrix example using code formatting so that we can better understand what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: I’m trying to find a value within a matrix at points x and y, that is within Access in a similar manner as index and match are used within Excel and I’m not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your matrix has two dimensions, you would supply the `DLookup` function with two criteria, e.g.:

```vb
DLookup("FieldContainingValue", "YourTable", "X=1 and Y=2")
```

Here:

- `FieldContainingValue` is the field containing the value you are looking to obtain.
- `YourTable` is the table or query containing the data
- `X` & `Y` are the fields containing the values on each 'axis' of the matrix.

Comment: So since the user is entering the values for x and y, which would be the intersection point, my code would look like:  dlookup (“time”, “table”, “x and y”) where x and y are used for the intersection point with a numeric value? Since I’m after the numeric value of the intersection

Comment: No, more like `DLookup ("time", "table", "field1=x and field2=y")`

Comment: It’s not working and neither is my function asking for the x and y values.

Comment: The `x` & `y` in my code are simply placeholders for the values you intend to use.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your assistance with this matter

Comment: Hello! I hope that all is well with you. I’ve done some research, had some sleep, and LOTS of caffeine. I’m still having issues with the DLookup function in Access. I have tried Transport =DLookup(“Time”, “mutable”, “CurrentNode and DestNode”) and many other variations of the above code. Unfortunately, nothing seems to be working for me. I did try what you suggested, but that didn’t work for me either. Do you have any other suggestions? Should I be using ELookup? Is there a difference? I really appreciate all of your assistance with the matter.

Comment: You aren't specifying what values those fields should hold, i.e.: `DLookup("Time", "mutable", "CurrentNode=SomeValue and DestNode=SomeValue")` Also, note that you are using non-standard double quotes (`“` = U+201C) as opposed to the standard double quote (`"` = U+0022)

Comment: Thank you!! I will try it in the morning and let you know. Thank you so much!!

Comment:  it’s still not working. . I sure do appreciate all of your assistance. Thank you

Comment: @Divingmickey If you were to edit your question and show the content of your `mutable` table, then we could better assist you.

Comment: I think that I figured it out. If my idea doesn’t work out could we do a private conversation?

Comment: Good morning. So, I rearranged my table so that I have three columns. However, in order to find the value the user will need to enter in a starting and an ending node. Access should then use both user entry’s to find the value. How do I use Dlookup to do this or is there an other way to do this within Access?

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest that you edit your question to include changes to the original query, and also include information about your table, the data it contains, and the desired result. Members should not be expected to trawl through comments to glean all of the required information to formulate an answer. For your described setup, the answer I have provided should still apply, where `X` and `Y` are the two field names and `1` and `2` are placeholders for the values provided by the user.

Comment: Is there a way that I can upload a photo to this message board in order to better explain what I am attempting to do?

Comment: Ok. Let me see if I can explain this a little bit more. I’m asking a user to enter in both a starting node character (x) and an ending node character (y), passing these values in to the Dlookup function in Access. The Dlookup function would then need to use the user entered characters (x and y values) and find the numerical value intersecting the two characters. Then Access uses the looked up value in several calculations. The table that Dlookup is referencing has numerous values each referenced by an x and a y character. I hope that this helps and I thank you for all of your assistance

Comment: Please edit your question to include changes to the original query, and also include information about your table, the data it contains, and the desired result.